# What's the purpose of (dollar) slashy string in Groovy

Tags: groovy

Why there are (dollar) slashy strings since they can be interchanged with quote ones and then can be spared for other syntax usage?
Is there any proof of their irreplaceability?

Answer (score 8):

If you're defining a regular expression pattern, then slashy strings are useful as you don't need to escape backslashes, e.g.

```
/\s+/
```

However, if you need a forward slash in your pattern, you'd need a dollar slashy string, e.g.

```
$/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/$
```

[Or see the docs](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_dollar_slashy_string)

Comment: Can't you just use `\/`, then?

Comment: @Ky. Yes, you can!

Comment: @Ky, You can use `\/` in a slashy string but you can't have a backslash as the last character - at least not without using special tricks as per the doco. So if you have a string with many slashes and the escaping obscures the strings meaning or makes it difficult to easily cut-n-paste, or you need a slash as the last character, the dollar slashy will prove useful.

Comment: So it's analogous to a `#""#` raw string literal?